# how can I change the browser toolbar color in my web application?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, colors, background-color

### how can I change the browser toolbar color in my web application?

[image]

there are many solutions on android apps and websites(mobile view)

I added those lines but it isn't working for desktop browsers.

Help me to find out the solution...

```html
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#4F46E5" />
    <!-- Windows Phone -->
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4F46E5" />
    <!-- iOS Safari -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#4F46E5" />
```